# Google Cloud Vision API. Golang . How to get API JSON

Tags: go, google-cloud-vision

I use Google Cloud Vision API with the Go SDK.
In some cases I don't want to use Golang structures to read API results, I just want to get full JSON response of an API call. For example,

```
// detectDocumentText gets the full document text from the Vision API for an
// image at the given file path.
func detectDocumentTextURI(w io.Writer, file string) error {
        ctx := context.Background()

        client, err := vision.NewImageAnnotatorClient(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        image := vision.NewImageFromURI(file)
        annotation, err := client.DetectDocumentText(ctx, image, nil)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        if annotation == nil {
                fmt.Fprintln(w, "No text found.")
        } else {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "API Response %s", ...JSON...)
        }

        return nil
}
```

How can I get that JSON from annotation structure? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Is there something in particular you're looking for in the JSON? You could pretty-print the response object as JSON, if you trying to explore what's returned:

```
json, err := json.MarshalIndent(annotation, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(json))
```

It's a bit difficult to get the raw JSON response from this call because under the hood it's using gRPC, not JSON. If you follow the client code for a bit (it's open source), you'll eventually get to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/vision/apiv1/image_annotator_client.go#L142:

```
func (c *ImageAnnotatorClient) BatchAnnotateImages(ctx context.Context, req *visionpb.BatchAnnotateImagesRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) (*visionpb.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse, error)
```

You can see that function build up the request, send it, and return the response (the same proto response you get from calling the original function, restricted to `res.FullTextAnnotation`). See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/vision/apiv1/client.go#L109.

Comment: Thanks. If there is gRPC used it is not possible to get  JSON than . I have to make a JSON manually.

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer with a snippet to pretty print JSON for the annotation response.